# How do I pass in matches via ProxyPassMatch?

Tags: apache-2.4, rewrite

I'm using `mod_proxy_fcgi` and I have this line in my vhost:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/housni-test/$1
```

I want a URL like `/media/4228dedb-9855-4894-84f5-47e4d3fd34c1/some-image-name.jpg` to point to `/index.php?id=4228dedb-9855-4894-84f5-47e4d3fd34c1&file=some-image-name.jpg`

Doing this with good 'ol mod_rewrite is works fine but with mod_proxy_fcgi, I'm not entirely sure especially because I can't pass in any matched expressions to the fcgi executor.

I basically need to match `^/media/([0-9a-z]{8}(?:-[0-9a-z]{4}){3}-[0-9a-z]{12})/([\w,\s-]+\.[A-Za-z]{3})$` and then pass it into `/index.php?id=$1&file=$2` but that's not possible with `ProxyPassMatch` as far as I know because anything after `?` seems to be ignored.

Comment: Have you tried to pass the values using ProxyPassMatch? It should work. (In fact, the classic example you used of: fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/housni-test/$1
 passes in a value with the $1 at the end.) If it doesn't work for some reason, though, you might look at using [mod_rewrite with the P (proxy) flag set](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p).

Comment: Also, if the issue is that $2 has no effect, it looks like you don't have a reference for $2, i.e. you did not enclose `[\w,\s-]+\.[A-Za-z]{3}` in parentheses, i.e. `([\w,\s-]+\.[A-Za-z]{3})`

Comment: I'll look at the link you posted. I've updated my regexp. That was just a typo on my part. I'm not sure, though, how to pass `$2` through.

Comment: According to the documentation, the `P` flag will take a performance hit but performance is a major concern for what I'm doing.